# tiddlywiki: can't save changes in QWebView

Tags: qt, pyqt, save, savechanges, tiddlywiki

I am trying to use `tiddlywiki` (version 5.1.10) together with `QWebView` in PyQt (version 4.10.2). 
I am able to load the tiddlywiki page with `QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("C:\\path\\to\\tiddlywiki\\empty.html")`, but unfourtunately my changes aren't saved.
I already tried to place `TiddlySaver.jar` in the same directory as tiddlywiki, but that doesn't change anything. 
Does somebody know if it's possible to use tiddlywiki together with `QWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

As nobody has answered here, I want to quickly respond with my "solution". After all, I couldn't get `tiddlywiki` to work in `PyQt4`...I researched it a little bit and it seems like that it isn't possible with `QWebView` (correct me, if I'm wrong).

Therefore, I looked for alternatives to `tiddlywiki`. My requirements were, that it shouldn't require any installation. That's why I decided to use `tiddlywiki` in the first place. After some googling, I found `Dokuwiki on a stick`. It's a pretty nice looking wiki, that doesn't require any installation. It is possible to download the wiki with or without a webserver (`dokuwiki on a stick provides` a `microapache` webserver, which is a really small apache webserver binary that doesn't need an installation). The cool thing is, that you can pack the `microapache` webserver to your PyQt application. When your application starts, you start the webserver locally (with `QProcess` or something similar) and can connect to the wiki.